# Error in building workspace For Eclipse for Python Android Programming

Tags: android, python, eclipse, workspace, sl4a

I already import the projects but when I cleaned them, there's an error.
Please help me to fix it. I'm stuck.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'PyDroid'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'Python32APK'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'PythonAPK'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I removed project/s from package explorer and re-imported again. so go to your project right click and select delete (make sure don't delete from disk) and then go file/import and browse it again. If your project is on your work space, just cut and paste in different location and than import from there. hope this help.